# R histogram that sums rather than frequency

Tags: r, histogram

I am new at using R and I am trying to produce a histogram where the axis shows a sum of another column rather than just a frequency count.

**example**
I have a matrix with two columns, RATE and BALANCE.  I would like to produce a histogram that shows the sum of balance rather than just record count.

`hist(mydata$RATE)` #only shows frequency.  How do i get it to sum `mydata$BALANCE`

I would like to produce a histogram that sums the BALANCE column rather than just doing a record count.   something like `hist(mydata$RATE, mydata$BALANCE)` but obviously the hist function doesn't appear to take a sum parameter

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to plot a bar plot. The corresponding function `barplot` might help.

First, as suggested by @DWin, [create some reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269):

```
set.seed(1) # Sets the starting seed for pseudo-random number generation
mydata <- data.frame(RATE = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE),
  BALANCE = rpois(100, 15) * 10)
```

Then create the summary data using the function `tapply`. This will calculate the sum of your `BALANCE` variable over each value of your `RATE` variable.

```
plotdata <- tapply(mydata$BALANCE, mydata$RATE, FUN = sum)
```

Then plot that using `barplot`:

```
barplot(plotdata)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's not an example that we can test to see if it meets your expectations, (and it's also not exactly clear what you do mean by "taking a sum parameter"),  but try this:

```
hist( cumsum( mydata$BALANCE) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.  I'll try and expand.  The function hist(mydata$RATE) will produce a histogram of all the rates by count (i.e. frequency).  Instead of having the count of the rates, i would like it to sum the balance column in the matrix.  I can get something similar using a barplot.  Except a barplot isn't broken into buckets.  HistData <- tapply(mydata$SUM, list(mydata$IRTE),sum)
barplot(HistData)

Comment: I did display "sum of the BALANCE", at least one type of sum. Now you are bringing in yet a third column named 'IRTE'. PLEASE PRESENT AN EXAMPLE!