# Histogram of sum instead of frequency - R

Tags: r, histogram

I want to plot an histogram where the y-axis represent the sum of a column. 
I found this example for categorical data:
[R histogram that sums rather than frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741443/r-histogram-that-sums-rather-than-frequency).
However, this is not what I am looking for, as it does not apply for continuous data, where I would have to define the bins.

Let's say I have x and y:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(y = runif (100, min= 0, max = 1),
                 x = rpois(100, 15) * 10)
```

A traditional histogram will be like:

```
hist (mydata$x)
```

[image]

Now how can I get the cumulative sum of y in the y-axis?

Comment: Use `cumsum()` to create a variable with the cumulative sum and use that to plot a histogram? As in `cumsum(mydata$x)`

Comment: A histogram is univariate. You need to more clearly describe what you're looking for.

Comment: @AlexA. I get the same histogram. Maybe it's just an R version thing.

Comment: So, you want to use the automatic binning from `hist` to automatically bin the `x` values, group `y`s together based on the `x` bin, sum the y's within each group, and plot the cumulative sum of y vs the x grouping?

Comment: `with(mydata, aggregate(y, by=list(bin=cut(x, nclass.Sturges(x))), FUN=sum))`. That does what @Gregor said.

Comment: Then you can just do `with(<previous comment>, barplot(cumsum(y), names.arg=bin))`

Comment: Sorry @AlexA. but how would I plot that as an histogram?

Comment: The closest you'd get using the approach I mentioned in a comment would be to use `barplot()`, unless someone knows a better way.

Comment: Also to reflect the eventual answer you wanted below, you might change your original question to remove the mention of a cumulative sum, since that's not what's being calculated here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to solve this problem that leverages the hist() function for most of the heavy lifting, and has the advantage that the barplot of the cumulative sum of y matches the bins and dimensions of the histogram of x:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(y = runif (100, min= 0, max = 1), x = rpois(100, 15) * 10)
mx <- mydata$x
my <- mydata$y

h <- hist(mydata$x)

breaks <- data.frame(
    "beg"=h$breaks[-length(h$breaks)], 
    "end"=h$breaks[-1]
)

sums <- apply(breaks, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) { sum(my[ mx >= x[1] & mx < x[2] ]) })

h$counts <- sums
plot(h, ylab="Sum", main="Sum of y Within x Bins")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry @ForrestR.Stevens, why do you get such high values in the y axis? Y varies from 0 to 1, it's sum should be always lower than 100 considering we have 100 repetitions of y. Right? I guess here you are not using information of y at all, are you?

Comment: If I understood your original question you wanted the sum of all values contained within the original frequency bins, correct?  The value on the y-axis represents that sum, and sums of over 2000 are normal for 15 values of over 150?  If you want the sum of y within those bins then you could replace d in the sum() call with mydata$y.  I can change the answer to reflect this is what you'd like?

Comment: Ah, I see from your answer where I was confused with your original question.  My apologies.  I've updated my answer so you can feel free to accept your own answer depending on which fits the bill better.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I have just edited my answer as well! I actually wanted y sum within bin and not cumulative sum! Thanks!

Comment: Heh, ok. Well, I'm glad to see we were both confused.  I've edited my answer to *not* use cumulative sums then.

Answer (score 4):

Summarizing all comments, this is what I wanted to have. Thanks @Alex A.

```
set.seed(1)

mydata <- data.frame(y = runif (100, min= 0, max = 1), x = rpois(100, 15) * 10)

a <- aggregate(mydata$y, by=list(bin=cut(mydata$x, nclass.Sturges(mydata$x))), FUN=sum)
a$bin<- gsub (']','',as.character (a$bin))
a$bin<- gsub (',',' ',as.character (a$bin))

ab2=sapply(strsplit(as.character(a$bin), " "), "[", 2)
barplot(a$x, names.arg=ab2)
```

[image]